# Request Entity Too Large - NextCloud in Docker

Tags: php, apache, nginx, docker, proxy

I am running Docker on CentOS with the [official nextcloud image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/), an [Nginx reverse proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/), and the [companion Let's Encrypt Cert Manager](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

When I try to upload files larger than about 1MB, I get the error `Request Entity Too Large`. Per what I've found online (https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/32 and others), I have added `client_max_body_size 10G;` to the proxy's nginx.conf, and to /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default.conf and /etc/nginx/vhost.d/files.example.com.conf. I have also changed .htaccess to `php_value upload_max_filesize 10G` and `php_value post_max_size 10G`. However, The `Request Entity Too Large` error still occurs.

Is there somewhere else I am forgetting to add the max size?

---

**`docker run` commands**

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
    --name nginx-proxy -v /var/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro \
    -v /etc/nginx/vhost.d -v /usr/share/nginx/html \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    --label com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true \
    jwilder/nginx-proxy

docker run -d -v /var/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    --volumes-from nginx-proxy jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

docker run --name nextcloud -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=files.example.com" \
    -d -v /etc/nginx/vhost.d/:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro \
    -v /var/nextcloud/:/var/www/html nextcloud
```

**nginx.conf in the proxy container**

```
#user html;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        client_max_body_size 10G;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        client_max_body_size 10G;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        }
    }

}
```

**.htaccess in the nextcloud container**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
       RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    # Add security and privacy related headers
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Download-Options "noopen"
    Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
  </IfModule>

  # Add cache control for static resources
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|svg|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15778463"
  </FilesMatch>

  # Let browsers cache WOFF files for a week
  <FilesMatch "\.woff$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
  php_value post_max_size 10G
  php_value memory_limit 512M
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
  php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
  php_value output_buffering 0
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv htaccessWorking true
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
  php_value post_max_size 10G
  php_value memory_limit 512M
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
  php_value output_buffering 0
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv htaccessWorking true
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*
  RewriteRule ^(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
  AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>
#### DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE ####

ErrorDocument 403 //core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 //core/templates/404.php
```

Comment: Is there any other proxy in the middle of your request?

Comment: @Robert I don't think so, just the apache in nextcloud and the nginx proxy.

Comment: So, you see that error in the nginx error log? Or just in the web browser?

Comment: In the web browser when I try to upload the file or in the nextcloud client

Comment: If it is an nginx limitation, you should see that error in its error log. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Yes, I see it in the nginx log: `nginx.1    | 2017/06/02 20:37:51 [error] 23#23: *2013 client intended to send too large body: 1695103 bytes, client: 172.17.0.1, server: files.example.com, request: "PUT /remote.php/webdav/32312416415_b90892af0a_o.jpg HTTP/2.0", host: "files.example.com"`